# Web parts documentation for SharePoint 2010

Tags: development, web-part

I can't seem to find the documentation for Web Part development on SharePoint 2010. I need all the details, connectable web parts, custom verbs etc and what has changed since MOSS 2007.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need if you are studying for exam 70-573.

MSDN: Web Parts in SharePoint Foundation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476318.aspx

MSDN: System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.aspx

MSDN: Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx

MSDN: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute Class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute%28VS.90%29.aspx

*Logging and Debugging*

MSDN: What's New In Logging for SharePoint Foundation 2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ee535240.aspx

MSDN: Using the Developer Dashboard
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff512745.aspx

MSDN: Using SPMonitoredScope
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512758.aspx

MSDN: Logging For SharePoint Developers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535537.aspx

MSDN: Overview of Unified Logging System (ULS) Logging
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512738.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The Developer Training Kit has some documentation and hands on labs in it:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=83A80A0F-0906-4D7D-98E1-3DD6F58FF059&displaylang=en

The SharePoint 2010 SDK is available at:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f0c9daf3-4c54-45ed-9bde-7b4d83a8f26f&displaylang=en

The Patterns and Practices group put together some walk-thrus at: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=64b55569-2168-4545-8b7c-f185b2cf967d&displaylang=en

I think each of these downloads covers web parts and they are all updated for 2010.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/ASP-Net-2-0-Web-Parts-Action/dp/193239477X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1282035646&sr=8-3. 
Can I apply the info in this book to SharePoint web parts as well?

Comment: In general, yes.  But it will not be current for SharePoint 2010.